# TraMineR - standard deviation and CI for mean plot

Tags: r, traminer

I was wondering if there is a function in `TraMineR` for computing the standard deviation. I am quite interested further on to add confidence intervals to the `seqmtplot` (mean plot).

My sequence (small sample of my data)

```
seq_time = seqdef(dt)
seqmeant(seq_time) * 10
```

In my particular case I need to multiply by 10 the `seqmeant` results.

First question, is there a build-in function to retreive the standart deviation ?

Second question, 
Is there a way to add CI to the

```
seqmtplot(seq_time)
```

[image]

Thanks a lot.

The sample

```
   dt = structure(c("e nuclear and acquaintance", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", 
"d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", "j work study sleep", 
"d nuclear", "a alone", "j work study sleep", "c child", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
"d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
"j work study sleep", "d nuclear", "a alone", "j work study sleep", 
"c child", "e nuclear and acquaintance", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", 
"d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", "j work study sleep", 
"d nuclear", "a alone", "j work study sleep", "c child", "d nuclear", 
"d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
"j work study sleep", "d nuclear", "c child", "j work study sleep", 
"c child", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", 
"e nuclear and acquaintance", "j work study sleep", "d nuclear", 
"c child", "j work study sleep", "c child", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", 
"d nuclear", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", "a alone", 
"d nuclear", "c child", "j work study sleep", "c child", "d nuclear", 
"d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
"a alone", "d nuclear", "c child", "j work study sleep", "c child", 
"d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
"b partner", "d nuclear", "c child", "j work study sleep", "c child", 
"d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
 "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "c child", "j work study sleep", "c child", 
"d nuclear", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
"e nuclear and acquaintance", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "c child", 
"j work study sleep", "c child", "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
"e nuclear and acquaintance", "e nuclear and acquaintance", "d nuclear", 
 "d nuclear", "d nuclear", "j work study sleep", "c child"), .Dim = 10:11, .Dimnames = list(
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), c("10:30", 
"10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", 
"11:50", "12:00", "12:10")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no built in function in `TraMineR` to get the standard deviation of the time spent in states. Here is how you can compute this standard deviation and the standard error of the mean time spent in the different states

```
dt.statd <- seqistatd(dt_time)

mt <- apply(dt.statd, 2, mean)
sdt <- apply(dt.statd, 2, sd)
se.mt <- sdt/sqrt(nrow(dt.statd))
## using 2*se.mt as approximate error margins
mtime <- data.frame(mean = mt, sdev = sdt, se.mean = se.mt, ci.L=mt-2*se.mt, ci.U=mt+2*se.mt)

round(mtime, 3)
```

If you have weighted sequences, you will have to consider weighted means and standard deviation. Here is an example with the `mvad` data

```
library(TraMineR)
data(mvad)
mvad.lab <- c("employment", "further education", "higher education",
              "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.shortlab <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86], states = mvad.shortlab,
                   labels = mvad.lab, weights = mvad$weight, xtstep = 6)

## state distribution in each sequence
mvad.statd <- seqistatd(mvad.seq)

library(SDMTools) ## for weighted mean and std
mt <- apply(mvad.statd, 2, wt.mean, w = mvad$weight)
sdt <- apply(mvad.statd, 2, wt.sd, w = mvad$weight)
se.mt <- sdt/sqrt(sum(mvad$weight))
mtime <- data.frame(mean = mt, sdev = sdt, se.mean = se.mt)
round(mtime, 3)
```

To add error bars on the plot, consider the `errbar` function from the `Hmisc` package.

Hope this helps.

============

The computation of the standard errors of the meant times and the plot of the error bars is available in `TraMineR` since version 1.8-11. See the help pages of functions `seqmeant` and `plot.stslist.meant`.